# Warnings in R after "fitdistr" used

Tags: r, fitting

I have just tried to fit a t-dist in R for some data, and did this by reading in a 21x1 csv file and converting to numeric (can show code used if you think it's important).
It has produced parameters but with 27 warnings all saying `1: In log(s) : NaNs produced` etc up to 26: and one saying `In sqrt(diag(vc)) : NaNs produced`.
Does this affect the validity of the parameters it has come back with?

I also just noticed it has 2 values for mean, sd and df. One on top and one below in brackets? what do these mean?

```
        m               s               df      
  -0.0001337445    0.0034887033   10.0256862670 
 ( 0.0008246931) ( 0.0000891192) (          NaN)
There were 27 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

Comment: "Does this affect the validity of the parameters it has come back with?" may be on-topic here. @user41024, can you provide your data, or at least some example data that would allow people to reproduce what you find?

Comment: Code used to turn list to numeric: dataNum <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = dim(data)[1], ncol = dim(data)[2])...not sure if this is valid for my data (which is 21x1 in csv file). The data is log increments of a stock index close price over a month

Comment: I suspect there may be no real issue here, but the underlying fitting routine perhaps was exploring some invalid parameters, such as negative values of $s$ or $df$.  (This can happen even with some constrained optimization code, unfortunately.)  We can check such possibilities if you would post a reproducible problem. For instance, it would be easy to paste the 21 numbers into your question so we can see them.

Comment: sure - 0.0009507
-0.0056441
0.0009551
-0.0068531
0.0028059
-0.000295
-0.0007378
0.0107188
-0.0010229
-0.000585
-0.0004389
-0.0003659
-0.0081585
-0.0046603
0.0032571
-0.0011832
0.0011832
0.0042037
0.003673
-0.0002933
0.00022
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This often happens when internally some of the results were invalid, like logarithms of non-positive numbers. In my experience, I have found `fitdistr` to be very "fragile". Sometimes you will still get results, other times (often with gammas) `fitdistr` just fails. You are almost always better off writing a small function to return the negative loglikelihood, and passing it directly into `optim` using Nelder-Mead (to dispense with calculating derivatives, although `deriv3` often works).

Comment: Instead of using `optim()` directly, I would rather use the `bblme` package. It’s more robust, and has some nice convenience functions (e.g. for profile likelihood confidence intervals). The [`bblme` vignettte](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bbmle/vignettes/mle2.pdf) has information on how to use the package, with example code.

Comment: Personally, I use `nloptr` directly and write my own loglikelihood functions and gradients, but de gustibus non est disputandum :).